# `Firebase/Auth` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, firebase

Google just updated their Firebase core of products and several old methods are deprecated. One I aim to integrate is: `Firebase/Auth`, however, importing into the podfile, and running: `pod install`, yields the error:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/Auth` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Auth` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

However, when looking at the build target, I have it set to the latest version:

[image]

How can I alleviate this error?

Comment: did you get the answer? I am also stuck here in this problem. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved updating my pod file.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

pod 'Firebase/Core'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do

target 'Unity-iPhone Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved updating my pod file, and put all requirement pods in the last of file, like this:

```
target 'UITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths

end
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
#End of file
```

And run in a terminal:

```
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

I did more or less than the guy told us 
but my steps were a little different:

1) on the Terminal: 
    go to your project folder: 
  1.1) cd Desktop/YourApp
   1.2) YOURMAC:YourApp Fernanda$ sudo pod init

2) change your file Podfile to:

Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'YourApp' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for YourApp
pod 'Firebase'

end

3) on the Terminal:  pod install

4) Now, change your file Podfile again to:

Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project platform :ios, '8.0' 
 target 'YourApp' do 
 # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks 
 use_frameworks! 
 # Pods for YourApp 
 pod 'Firebase' 
 pod 'Firebase/Auth' 
 end

5)  on the Terminal:  pod update
 
Sorry my about my English, 
Good Look!